# Excel VBA - Formula Breaks After Adding Data in Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[[image: Error Message After Running Code][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJkux.jpg)

[[image: Line where code breaks][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acfHD.jpg)

All of my code was working great, until I added numbers to Row 5 in my spreadsheet.  After I added the data, my COUNTIFS formula no longer returns the correct result.

For Row 5, MonthsWithValues should equal 10; however, each time I run the code now, it gives me a 0.  I have tried debugging it using Step Into, Break Points/Toggle Points, and Watch.  Each time I run the code, it keeps saying the value of MonthsWithValue is 0.  Help!

Code:

```
For i = 5 To LastRow
MonthsWithValues = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>0", .Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>""")
Next i
```

Comment: your code seems too long compared to your description, please keep only the part which is relevant. Have you tried debugging it (see here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/802/introduction-to-vba/15512/debugging#t=201608021947001355751)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried debugging it with no success.  The relevant code is:                                                                                                           `For i = 5 to LastRow                                                            MonthsWithValues = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>0", .Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>""")
Next i`

Comment: please edit your question instead of answering in a comment. "Yes, I have tried debugging it with no success" - what you've exactly tried?

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I have edited my question above.

Comment: does it works correctly for the other rows? Can you please add some screenshots?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for any of the rows.  I tried adding 2 screenshots above.  I can't tell if they work or not since my work blocks certain links/sites.  Can you see the screen shots?

Comment: When I looked online the .CountIf() only takes two args.  What I suspect is that the MonthsWithValues isn't initalized with a number so it is being evaluated to 0 (Giving you the div by zero error) in the .CountIf().  Try breaking up your .CountIf() statement like here with only two arg's per .CountIf() and see if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894091/vba-if-countifs  BTW: this should really be flagged as a SO question, not a SU.  You may want to add an if statement that handles a MonthsWithValues == 0 situation.

Comment: @Musselman She's using `countifs`, which can take multiple arguments. See the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196714.aspx.

Comment: Is this inside a `with` block? If so, what is the block's object?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the third argument to countifs:

```
MonthsWithValues = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>0", "<>""")
```

Only the first argument to countifs should be a range; *all* others should be criteria. You're essentially giving your range as a criteria. Excel is accepting it (I'm not sure why, but maybe it's comparing the values with the first value of the range), but it's not correct for the results you desire.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @j_foster, but when I removed the third argument, I still received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

@Musselman, you were correct.  It was giving me the error because `MonthsWithValues` wasn't being initialized with a number, so it was being evaluated to 0.

The correct code is:

```
Sub ReduceCost_Percentage()

With Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet")

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim Orig2016Total(68) As Long
Dim MonthsWithValues(68) As Long

For i = 5 To LastRow
Orig2016Total(i) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(("BC" & i), ("BN" & i)))
MonthsWithValues(i) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>0", .Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>""""")
Next i
```

Now it works! Thanks for the help everyone!